# what is the exact command to shut down a redhat linux system

Tags: linux

I want to know the exact command to shut down a Red Hat linux server.

I was using `init 0`, but some one said it's not the proper method to shut down my linux server.

If not, what command should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ shutdown -h now
```

or

```
$ telinit 0
```

Comment: `init` and `telinit` do exactly the same when invoked by user.

Comment: As I just noted on another answer: On Red Hat, the `shutdown` command may be in `/sbin/shutdown`, which (at least on the Red Hat machine I just shut down) may not be in the default path, so you might have to invoke the full path to the command, as opposed to just `shutdown`. Your mileage may vary, depending on your exact install details...

Answer (score 8):

Try `poweroff` .

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: @ChristianVielma and others: The `shutdown` command may be in `/sbin/shutdown`, which (at least on the Red Hat machine I just shut down) may not be in the default path, so you might have to invoke the full path to the command, as opposed to just `shutdown`. Will also add this note onto the top-rated answer.

Answer (score 6):

To reboot from the prompt, type:

```
$ shutdown -r now
```

Or, if you want to exit from your system and turn off your machine, type:

```
$ shutdown -h now
```

.. via [manuals](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-6.1-Manual/getting-started-guide/s1-basics-shutting-down.html).

Comment: You beat my answer by 29 secs :D

Comment: there is also "reboot"

Answer (score 4):

shutdown -h now